# Value posts of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, android-volley

1.this is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        apiService api = new apiService(this);
        try {
            api.jsonrecived(new apiService.GetdataRecived() {
                                @Override
                                public void getdata(List<post> posts) {
                                    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
                                    recycleradapter recycleradapter = new recycleradapter(MainActivity.this,posts);
                                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleradapter);

                                }
                            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

2.this is Json (http://192.168.1.4/untitled/GetData.php)

> "posts": [{"id":"1","title":"title1","content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, ","image_url":"127.0.0.1/untitled/uploads/pic1.jpg","date":"0000-00-00"},{"id":"2","title":"title2","content":"hello server","image_url":"127.0.0.1/untitled/uploads/pic2.jpg","date":"0000-00-00"},{"id":"3","title":"title3","content":"Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn\u2019t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then ","image_url":"127.0.0.1/untitled/uploads/pic3.jpg","date":"0000-00-00"},{"id":"4","title":"title4","content":"voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos ","image_url":"127.0.0.1/untitled/uploads/pic4.jpg","date":"0000-00-00"},{"id":"5","title":"title5","content":"ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, ","image_url":"127.0.0.1/untitled/uploads/pic5.jpg","date":"0000-00-00"},{"id":"6","title":"title6","content":"provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id ","image_url":"127.0.0.1/untitled/uploads/pic6.jpg","date":"0000-00-00"}]

3.this is apiService.java

```
public class apiService {

    private static final String TAG = "apiService";
    private Context context;

    public apiService(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public void jsonrecived(GetdataRecived getdataRecived)throws JSONException
    {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET
                , "http://192.168.1.4/untitled/GetData.php"
                , null
                , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                List<post> pos = new ArrayList<>();
                post post = new post();
                for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length() ; i++)
                {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("posts");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        post.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                        post.setTitleview(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        post.setContentview(jsonObject.getString("content"));
                        post.setDateview(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                        post.setImageview(jsonObject.getString("image_url"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, "catch: "+e );
                    }
                    pos.add(post);
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);

            }

        }
                , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error);
            }
        });

        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000 , DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    public interface GetdataRecived
    {
        void getdata(List<post> posts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line has the error? Stack trace?

Comment: Do you get a response? Is response != null?

Comment: you need to put the exception, all of it, also what do you see if you open this url `http://192.168.1.4/untitled/GetData.php` in regular browser? put that too in the question

Comment: Your `apiService` is a little out of order. You want your `for` loop to be iterating through the `jsonArray.length()`, not the `response.length()`

Comment: Inside your `onResponse` method, you should first get the `jsonArray` and then iterate on each of its elements.

So move your `JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("posts");` right above your `for` loop, and change your for loop to: `for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++)`